# Containerizing web apps with static files

Tags: docker, nginx

I currently use NGINX as reverse proxy for multiple web applications (virtual hosts) hosted on a Linux server. It also serves static files for the applications (eg big Javascripts,  bitmaps, software downloads) directly.

Now I want to package each application into a docker image. But what do I do with the static files?

I can either serve these files from the applications (which is slower)  or have another images per application with it's own NGINX just for the static files.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Had recently configured a django application which had such a similar constrain as it had static files and need to run python migrate command. We resolved the issue of static files by using a bucket to store the static files and then invoked the bucket in our python code.

Answer (score 1):

Good news - you do pretty much exactly what you're already doing.  Basically you'll use the Nginx official image and just copy the files into the appropriate directory.

The Dockerfile would look something like this for create-react-app (as an example):

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir -p /app 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build 

from nginx:alpine 
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Hosting containers on cloud infrastructure can come with its challenges though.  The company I work for, [cycle.io](https://cycle.io), simplifies the process and would be a great place for you to deploy your containerized server.

Comment: But that would give me one NGINX per app. but I need one for all (I have only  one IP address with multiple DNS names (one per app)

Comment: This is just an example - Im saying that you can modify this example to serve all your files similar to how you use Nginx now. If they're all static files, you just dump them in the nginx container and then modify the nginx configuration / routing to do what you need.

Comment: My goal was to have one container per app (containing everything the app needs (ie application server + static files)). And one nginx for all apps together.